# Making a button with "Next 3 images"

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, button

I have 3 images and I want to make a button with Previous ,  Next

When "Next" button is clicked, I want my those 3 images to dissapear and another 3 new images to appear on the same location.

I have this code, but I don't know what to do further. (LIVE VERSION: vestigedayz.com/Arrow )

```js
var slideIndex = 1;
showDivs(slideIndex);

function plusDivs(n) {
  showDivs(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentDiv(n) {
  showDivs(slideIndex = n);
}

function showDivs(n) {
  var i;
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("demo");
  if (n > x.length) {
    slideIndex = 1
  }
  if (n < 1) {
    slideIndex = x.length
  }
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
    dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" w3-red", "");
  }
  x[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
  dots[slideIndex - 1].className += " w3-red";
}
```

```css
.mySlides {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-3">
  <div class="movie_img">
    <div class="grid_2">
      <a href="/seriale/Revolution">
        <img src="images/pic6.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="">
      </a>
      <div class="caption1">
        <ul class="list_5 list_7">
          <li><i class="icon5"> </i>
            <p>6,7</p>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <i class="icon4 icon6 icon7"> </i>
        <p class="m_3">Revolution</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="grid_2 col_1">
    <a href="/seriale/Almost-Human">
      <img src="images/pic2.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="">
    </a>
    <div class="caption1">
      <ul class="list_3 list_7">
        <li><i class="icon5"> </i>
          <p>8.1</p>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <i class="icon4 icon7"> </i>
      <p class="m_3">Almost Human</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="grid_2 col_1">
    <a href="/seriale/Intelligence">
      <img src="images/pic9.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="">
    </a>
    <div class="caption1">
      <ul class="list_3 list_7">
        <li><i class="icon5"> </i>
          <p>7,0</p>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <i class="icon4 icon7"> </i>
      <p class="m_3">Intelligence</p>
    </div>
  </div>


  <div class="w3-content">
    <img class="mySlides" src="images/pic2.jpg" style="width:100%">
    <img class="mySlides" src="images/pic9.jpg" style="width:100%">
    <img class="mySlides" src="images/pic6.jpg" style="width:100%">
  </div>

  <div class="w3-center">
    <div class="w3-section">
      <button class="w3-btn" onclick="plusDivs(-1)">❮ Anterior</button>
      <button class="w3-btn" onclick="plusDivs(1)">Ulterior ❯</button>
    </div>
  </div>



</div>
```

Comment: it would be much easier to help you if you create jsfiddle link

Comment: @VedranJukic  here is the live version. : http://vestigedayz.com/Arrow/

i think it would be much better to see the entire structure.

Comment: The working of code you provided and working of your live version are not same. Please provide the correct code so that we can help.

Comment: please isolate problem in jsfiddle :) so I (or someone else) can help you without inspecting the entire page. I don't think rest of the page is relevant to the problem

Comment: @VedranJukic https://jsfiddle.net/onozoafd/   - here it is. I've tried to fallow this tutorial http://www.w3schools.com/w3css/tryit.asp?filename=tryw3css_slideshow_dots

But without the button numbers.

Comment: @SidharthGusain https://jsfiddle.net/onozoafd/

Comment: @VedranJukic  i want to do something like imdb's.  http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2193021/?ref_=tt_rec_tt

Check "Next 6, prev 6"    but instead of table, I want to fade in my those 3 images and fade in new 3 images.  And vice-versa, when "prev 6" is clicked it will appear my old 3 images back.

Comment: if you want to fade in/out thumbs with your current html structure, it might be more complicated as you would need to use absolute positioning. checkout some jquery slider examples and try making sample app outside this project until you fully understand how to implement it in this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've simplifed html structure to help you solve the problem and made changes to js. You will be able to implement it on your current html structure with little effort.

```js
var slideIndex = 0;

// get html elements
  
var slidesEl = document.getElementById('thumbs');
var thumbs = slidesEl.getElementsByTagName('li');

showDivs(slideIndex);

function plusDivs() {
  showDivs(slideIndex += 3);
}

function currentDiv(n) {
  showDivs(slideIndex = n);
}

document.getElementById('prevbutton').onclick = function() {
 slideIndex -= 3;
  if (slideIndex < 0) {
   slideIndex = 0;
  }
  showDivs(slideIndex);
}

document.getElementById('nextbutton').onclick = function() {
 slideIndex += 3;
  // make sure that last 3 thumbs are alwas displayed
  if (slideIndex >= (thumbs.length - 3)) {
   slideIndex = thumbs.length - 3;
  }
  showDivs(slideIndex);
}

function showDivs(n) {
  
  // first hide all thumbs

 for (var i=0; i<thumbs.length; i++) {
   thumbs[i].style.display = 'none';
  }
  
  
  
  // show 3 slides from current index slide
  for (var i=slideIndex; i<slideIndex+3; i++) {
   thumbs[i].style.display = 'block';
  }
  
}
```

```html
<ul id="thumbs">
<!-- first 3 divs (visible) -->
<li>
  <a href="/seriale/Revolution">
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/5Qu0xhq.png" class="img-responsive" alt="">
  </a>
</li>
<li>
  <a href="/seriale/Almost-Human">
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/uOhgArC.png" class="img-responsive" alt="">
  </a>
</li>
<li>
  <a href="/seriale/Intelligence">
      <img src="http://i.imgur.com/dVatFEs.png" class="img-responsive" alt="">
    </a>
</li>
<!-- next 3 divs (hidden) -->
<li style="display: none;">
  <a href="/seriale/Intelligence">
      <img src="http://i.imgur.com/dVatFEs.png" class="img-responsive" alt="">
    </a>
</li>
<li style="display: none;">
  <a href="/seriale/Revolution">
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/5Qu0xhq.png" class="img-responsive" alt="">
  </a>
</li>
<li style="display: none;">
  <a href="/seriale/Almost-Human">
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/uOhgArC.png" class="img-responsive" alt="">
  </a>
</li>
<!-- next 3 divs (hidden) -->
<li style="display: none;">
  <a href="/seriale/Almost-Human">
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/uOhgArC.png" class="img-responsive" alt="">
  </a>
</li>
<li style="display: none;">
  <a href="/seriale/Revolution">
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/5Qu0xhq.png" class="img-responsive" alt="">
  </a>
</li>
<li style="display: none;">
  <a href="/seriale/Intelligence">
      <img src="http://i.imgur.com/dVatFEs.png" class="img-responsive" alt="">
    </a>
</li>
</ul>
<div class="w3-center">
    <div class="w3-section">
      <button id="prevbutton" class="w3-btn">❮ Anterior</button>
      <button id="nextbutton" class="w3-btn">Ulterior ❯</button>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: What should I edit or add ? I saw something in js. Because it won't change the images.

Comment: You will need to replace entire javascript snippet and do small modifications to html structure. In jsfiddle I've sent you above, you can see that it changes images (image links are same, but element are in different order so you can see that buttons work).
I've put comments in html and js. In your html structure you need to create wrapper element (in my example id="thumbs") and inside you can use div elements to wrap each slide. Then take a look at style attribute that hides all thumbs other than first three.